# php-cli:error while loading shared libraries

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I upgraded the ubuntu server to version 12.04.1. Since then php does not work anymore from cli. I did apt-get update / upgrade, removed php-cli, reinstalled it. no success.
the error message is:
php: error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I did not find libmysqlclient.so.16 but libmysqlclient.so.18 on the server.

How am I able to tell php-cli to use the newer version?

Comment: Maybe making a symbolic link from the new to the old file?

Comment: Have you tried downloading `libmysqlclient.so.16`?